# Как объединить две подсети в Cisco Packet Tracer в одну сеть через Router5 и Router0?

Tags: сеть, cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

На картинке снизу левая подсеть использует протокол rip2, а правая rip. Задание делаю в Cisco Packet Tracer. Уже спроектировал по отдельности две подсети и они работают, трассировки от компьютера к компьютера проходят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Останавливать Cisco роутеры не обязательно! и это же Cisco почему не EIGRP, были бы разные устройства не Cisco в ролях типа роутеры тогда конечно OSPF.

R0 если там включен RIP1 то внутри 
router rip  ( протокол классовой маршрутизации)
тут должны быть прописаны 2 сети 1.0/24, 2.0/24
дописать сеть  типа x.x.x.0/24 которая соединит R0 <-> R5 анонсы динамики должны проходить в другую сеть , но к сожалению такого не будет вот почему!

RIP2 является бесклассовым протоколом маршрутизатор R5 прослушивает только обновления RIPv2. Чтобы работала динамика между сетями должен быть один динамический протокол маршрутизации например RIP2. Если же нет то можно сделать с помощью команды
default-information originate.

Маршрутизатор R0 получает указание инициировать передачу информации, применяемой по умолчанию. Это достигается путем передачи статического маршрута по умолчанию в обновлениях RIP. Дальше я думаю все понятно :-) (маршрут последней надежды)

Команда show ip protocols отображает текущие настройки протокола маршрутизации IPv4 на маршрутизаторе. 
Команда show ip route отображает маршруты RIP, добавленные в таблицу маршрутизации.

Answer (score 0):

Остановить роутеры R5 и R0. Добавить сетевую карту в R5 и  в R0. Кинуть между роутерами линию, настроить ip, настроить динамическую маршрутизацию между R5 и R0, а так же анонсировать нужные сети в ospf